# VBA UserForm data to module

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to figure out how userfords are used. 
Basically I am trying to use a userform in order to send automatic emails.
I have figured out the module of automatic emails but had no luck to pass the data from the UserForm to the module. So I created another small module to see what might work for me but with no luck.
So the first UserForm is the below:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonCancel_Click()


Unload Me

End Sub

Public Sub CommandButtonOK_Click()

mailfromfor = mailtobeused.Text
smtpservername = smtpserver.Text
passmailfromform = mailpassword.Text

Me.Hide

End Sub
```

which is nothing fancy. A userform with three fields and an OK & Cancel buttons.

The next one is to test if the data from the form can be passed to the module.
So I created a button with the code like this:

```
Sub testvalue()


MsgBox mailfromfor
MsgBox smtpservername
MsgBox passmailfromform

End Sub
```

but nothing seems to work.
The MsgBoxes give me blanks.
Basically I have no idea how the UserForms work. What are the principles behind the code. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to pass the values using byval or byref to the sub you want to use the variables. Example below:

```
    Public Sub CommandButtonOK_Click()

    mailfromfor = mailtobeused.Text
    smtpservername = smtpserver.Text
    passmailfromform = mailpassword.Text

    testvalue mailfromfor, smtpservername, passmailfromform 'pass the values to the sub

    Unload Me

    End Sub

    Sub testvalue(ByVal mailfromfor As String, ByVal smtpservername As String, ByVal passmailfromform As String) 'set the values as byval

    MsgBox mailfromfor
    MsgBox smtpservername
    MsgBox passmailfromform

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SpyingShinx Thanx for answering. Please can you explain to me how the testvalue mailfromfor, smtpservername, passmailfromform works? I am new to VBA and I don't get many things. Also don't know the ByVal. I will have to google it to see how it works.

Comment: Doesn't work the way i need it. I want the two modules (form and module basically) to be two separate entities.

Answer (score 0):

the right way would be grabbing them form Userform fields before disposing it, as follows:

```
Sub testvalue()

    With New UserForm1 ' instantiate and reference an object of your Userfom class (change "UserForm1" to your actual Userform class
        .Show

        MsgBox .mailtobeused.Text ' get referenced userform 'mailtobeused' textbox value
        MsgBox .smtpserver.Text ' get referenced userform 'smtpserver' textbox value
        MsgBox .mailpassword.Text ' get referenced userform 'mailpassword' textbox value
    End With

End Sub
```

this way you don't even need those `mailfromfor`, `smtpservername` and `passmailfromform` variables in your Userfom module

Another way could be using `Public` variables, which I would advise against

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. I managed to get it to work yesterday but with Publick variables though. Why you would advice not to use them?

Comment: You are welcome. Public variables are as much handy as dangeorus in that they make your code prone to such drawbacks as unwanted/uncontrolled value changes or variable shadowing (just read about around here). I'd suggest you to get in the habit of using them as less as possible and, for starter, try and apply what I showed you in my answer. And possibly let me know